# VS 2015 CTP 6 - Can I target full asp.net 5 and reference local .net 4.5 projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get a basic asp.net 5 project running and the 1st issue is I can't seem to reference a .net 4.5 project that represents my data orm layer (NOT EF).

Does CTP6 only support .net core or can I tell it I want to use full?  I think I'm on CTP6 but don't know how to tell. The vs about just says ctp.

Has anybody gotten an asp.net 5 project to work referencing another local (non  nuget) .net 4.5 project?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can reference 4.5 class library from your solution, just add the reference as you do in old fashion and VS will update your `project.json` and create a wrap project in `wrap` folder, it will update the `global.json` too

**global.json sample**

```
{
    "sources": [
        "src",
    "wrap"
    ]
}
```

**wrap project .json sample**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../YourWrappedProject/YourWrappedProject.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../YourWrappedProject/obj/{configuration}/YourWrappedProject.dll",
        "pdb": "../../YourWrappedProject/obj/{configuration}/YourWrappedProject.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{
   ...

    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
                "YourWrappedProject": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "YourWrappedProject": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "YourWrappedProject": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can target core and/or full and/or 4.5 in an **ASP.Net 5 class library**

Comment: Thanks, I've tried what you suggest above and verified my files are like what you posted above, but it just doesn't work for me.  Two things happen, new errors appear in other places for things I haven't even touched and it just can't find the classes in the 4.5 class library.

Comment: Example: if I just add an empty "net45" section to my asp.net 5 frameworks section, the app stops compiling and I get tons of errors.

Comment: Witch runtime are you using? can you update your question with the kvm list output ?

Comment: you cannot use "net45" framework for a website only on class library to make portable class library

Comment: So ...  1)  asp.net 5 website is always only core?  2) asp.net 5 website can reference an asp.net 5 class library and that class library can use .net 45 but no .net 45 stuff can pass through to the website?

Comment: a asp.net 5 website can target aspnet50 or aspnetcore50, an asp.net class library can target net45, aspnet50 and aspnetcore50. those a framework targeting.

Comment: and you can wrap an old class library to set it as reference of aspnet project